# How to download and save a file using phonegap/cordova on Android

Tags: android, json, cordova, download, filereader

I am at my whit's end.
I will try to keep it brief.
Using Cordova/Phonegap 3.0 (and get the same results on 2.8.0). 
Android version 4.0.4.
Code works on BlackBerry10 (Q10 and Z10).

On Android it errors with a JSON Error (no, I'm not parsing JSON, this seems to come out of cordova's bowels). I will paste the JSON.stringified error object at the end of this.

So, on to code then:
First a filesystem success function:

```
function onFSSuccess(fileSystem) {
if (fileSystem == null) {
    window.alert("fileSystem is null");
}
var root = fileSystem.root; 
root.getDirectory("com.app.id",{create:true},gotDir,onError);};
```

Then a function to handle success with directory retrieval:

```
function gotDir(d){
    DATADIR = d;        
    doTheDl (d.fullPath + "/update.sql",fileTransfer);
};
```

Then the actual call to get the filesystem:

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFSSuccess, null);
```

Then a function to download the file:

```
function doTheDl (localPath,fileTransfer) {
    try {
        window.alert ("Downloading to '" + localPath + "'");
        fileTransfer.download (
            uri,
            localPath,
            function (entry) {
                try {
                    $("#dbDownloadProgressContainer").text("File saved to " + entry.name + ". Applying script to database...");
                    dbInitObj.applyUpdateScript(entry); 
                }
                catch (e) {
                    window.alert ( e);
                }

            },
            function (err) {
                window.alert ("ERROROR!!! - " + err);
                var errCodeName = err.code;
                switch (err.code) {
                    case FileTransferError.FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERR:
                        errCodeName ='FILE_NOT_FOUND_ERR';
                        break;
                    case FileTransferError.INVALID_URL_ERR:
                        errCodeName="INVALID_URL_ERR";
                        break;
                    case FileTransferError.CONNECTION_ERR:
                        errCodeName="CONNECTION_ERR";
                        break;
                    case FileTransferError.ABORT_ERR:
                        errCodeName="ABORT_ERR";
                        break;
                    default:
                        errCodeName = "UNKNOWN";
                        break;                      
                }
                window.alert ("Download failed: " + err.source + ", " + err.target + ", " + errCodeName);
            },
            true                
        );

    }
    catch (e) {
        window.alert ( e);
    }
}
```

Man, gotta love all these async callbacks...
Next we get to the heart of the matter, trying to READ the downloaded file:

```
//Bulk of applyUpdateScript script ommited, but eventually it gets here:

function readComplete (evt) {

    $("#dbDownloadProgressContainer").text("Parsing script file...");

    //Got this gem from here: http://beckism.com/2010/09/splitting-lines-javascript/
    var lines = evt.target.result.match(/^.*([\n\r]+|$)/gm);


    //var lineIndx = lines.length;

    window.setTimeout(function () {
            $("#dbDownloadProgressContainer").text("Processing " + lines.length + " statements");
},50);
};  

try {
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onloadend=readComplete;

        fileReader.onerror=function (err) {
            //var errStr = translateFileError (err);
            window.alert ("FileReader.onerror: " +JSON.stringify (err));
        };


        fileReader.onloadstart=function (evt) {
            window.alert ("FileReader.onloadstart - " + JSON.stringify (evt));
        };


        fileReader.onload=function (evt)
        {
            window.alert ("FileReader.onload - Called when the read has successfully completed.- " + JSON.stringify (evt));
        };


        fileReader.onprogress = function (evt)
        {
            window.alert ("FileReader.onprogress - " + JSON.stringify (evt));
        }

        fileReader.onabort = function (evt)
        {
            window.alert ("FileReader.onabort - " + JSON.stringify (evt));
        }


        function gotFile (fileEntry) {
            window.alert ("Activating reader for file '" + fileEntry.fullPath + "'");
            fileReader.readAsText(fileEntry);

        };

        function noFileFound (fileError) {
            alert ("Can not access database update script: code " + translateFileError (fileError));
        };

        // window.alert ("scriptPath.name = " + scriptPath.name);

        DATADIR.getFile (scriptPath.name,null,gotFile,noFileFound);
    }
    catch (e) {
        window.alert (e);
}
```

NOW, when I hit the reading bits, I eventually get this from the 'onerror' event (rember this is the JSON.stringfied error object:

```
{
   "type":"error",
   "bubbles":false,
   "cancelBubble":false,
   "cancelable":false,
   "lengthComputable":false,
   "loaded":0,
   "total":0,
   "target":{
      "_readyState":2,
      "_error":{
         "code":"JSON error"
      },
      "_result":null,
      "_fileName":"file:///mnt/sdcard/com.app.id/update.sql",
      "_realReader":{
         "error":null,
         "result":"",
         "readyState":0
      }
   }
}
```

Please also note that 'com.app.id' is a place holder for the actual app ID - can't paste that for fear of sensitive names. I did try other folder names as well.
Other notable(?) items:

- The download progress event seems to indicate that we are downloading precisely double the actual file size (wtf?)
- Results are the same on android device and emulator
- BlackBerry10 seems to work fine

Thanks in advance to any clever people....

Comment: Coincidently, the console.log I added to capture the error above, fell precisely on line 666. So maybe I should just give this up as "daemon possessed" and go open 'n bar on a beach in Mozambique.

Comment: OK, should have checked this waaaaay earlier - but in anycase, it seems the file is downloaded correctly to the SDCard, so that means something is going pear shaped just with the reading. Maybe a size limit? The file in question is about 12Mb....

Comment: OK, verified it's NOT size, the same thing happens with an 18Kb file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK.
This was the solution:

```
    function gotFile (fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.file (function (file) {
        fileReader.readAsText(file);
    });
};
```

So thanks a BAJILLION to this dude:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/?ModPagespeed=noscript

In case you missed it, the magic is the call to the "file(...)" function on the fileEntry object.
Why it works on the BB10 WITHOUT it....aarrgggghhh

Comment: FYI - I DID eventually run into a size issue when reading the 24Mb (which is supposed to be 12Mb) file. Got around that problem by dumping the entire above solution and implementing a partial download and process approach with the HTTP Range header.